# HTML 5 -Dynamic Elements as layers

Tags: html, image, layer

I want to implement Dynamic Elements as layers,one over the other.The layer which is above is translucent visually to the layer below.(that is where one layer has an element in which the image changes at regular intervals and another layer where the element has horizontally scrolling text)Is this possible? and if the answer is "yes",how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

for example try:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            window.onload = function () {

                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

                var img = new Image();
                img.src = 'http://rakstagemom.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/image-is-cumulus_clouds_panorama-from-wikipedia-commons.jpg';

                var addit = -0.4;
                var scrollSpeed = 0.01;
                var left = 0;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var _scale = document.documentElement.clientHeight / canvas.height;
                var width = canvas.width;
                var height = canvas.height;
                var max = -840;

                //animation loop
                var init = setInterval(function() {
                    left += addit;
                    if(left > -1) {
                        addit = -0.4
                    } else if(left < max)
                        addit = 0.4;
                    //0.4
                    ctx.drawImage(img, left, 0, width, height);
                    var thisFrameTime = ( thisLoop = new Date) - lastLoop;
                    frameTime += (thisFrameTime - frameTime) / filterStrength;
                }, scrollSpeed);
            };
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                overflow: hidden;
                background: #001;
            }
            .window {
                padding: 0;
                clear: none;
                border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                border-radius: 10px 10px 2px 2px;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            }
            #container {
                width: 91.5%;
                height: 10em;
                margin: .55em .9em .4em .85em;
                position: absolute;
                background: rgba(0,100,200,0.25);
            }
            #canvas1 {
                width: auto;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas1" width="1784px" height="534px"></canvas>
        <div id="container" class="window">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry about the image; just for demo purposes.